# Problem with character encoding of '

Tags: html

Why does this page

http://reboltutorial.com/cgi-bin/designpatterns-quiz.cgi

shows a ? in the sentence (at least on my firefox)

> ```
> Separates an object’s abstraction from its implementation
> ```

whereas I am using utf-8 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the site declares UTF-8 as its content type, but the `´` is a ISO-8859-1 encoded character. Switch your editor to UTF-8 and type it in again (this is the recommended way over using entities).

Comment: Hey thanks, I didn't know my notepad2 could do that :) It was in ANSI and I switched to UTF-8 it corrected, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Because whoever made that page actually encoded it iso-8859-1.

Answer (score 2):

Just *saying* you're using UTF-8 doesn't make it so.

Where does that character come from? Is it static content, or does it come from a database or so? If it's from the database, make sure your entire web application stack uses UTF-8 as well. I don't know what you're using, but I know [it's not straight-forward for PHP/Apache/MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through).

If it's static content, make sure you save your HTML files as UTF-8.

Contrary to what the others have said, by the way, that character is *not* an ISO-8859-1 character, but a [Windows-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) character.

Comment: What about B4 (in ISO-8859-1)?

Comment: Well, that *would* be ISO-8859-1, but the character on that tutorial page was `0x92`, which is decidedly absent from ISO-8859-1: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1#Codepage_layout

Comment: Unfortunately, ISO-8859-1 as used by web browsers has come to mean Windows code page 1252.